# How to implement an array-like property wrapper in python?

Tags: python, wrapper, ctypes

I have a class in python that acts as a front-end to a c-library. This library performs simulations and handles very large arrays of data. This library passes forward a `ctype` array and my wrapper converts it into a proper `numpy.ndarray`.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    @property
    def arr(self):
        return numpy.array(self._lib.get_arr())
```

However, in order to make sure that memory problems don't occur, I keep the ndarray data separate from the library data, so changing the ndarray does not cause a change in the true array being used by the library. However, I can pass along a new array of the same shape and overwrite the library's held array.

```
@arr.setter
def arr(self, new_arr):
    self._lib.set_arr(new_arr.ctypes)
```

So, I can interact with the array like so:

```
x = SomeClass()
a = x.arr
a[0] += 1
x.arr = a
```

My desire is to simplify this even more by allowing syntax to simply be `x.arr[0] += 1`, which would be more readable and have less variables. I am not exactly sure how to go about creating such a wrapper (I have very little experience making wrapper classes/functions) that mimics properties but allows item access as my example.

How would I go about making such a wrapper class? Is there a better way to accomplish this goal? If you have any advice or reading that could help I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could work. `Array` is a proxy for the Numpy/C array:

```
class Array(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #self.__lib = ...
        self.np_array = numpy.array(self._lib.get_arr())

    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        self.np_array = numpy.array(self._lib.get_arr())
        return self.np_array.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.np_array.__setitem__(key, value)
        self._lib.set_arr(new_arr.ctypes)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Delegate to NumPy array."""
        try:
            return getattr(self.np_array, name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError(
                 "'Array' object has no attribute {}".format(name))
```

Should behave like this:

```
>>> a = Array()
>>> a[1]
1
>>> a[1] = 10
>>> a[1]
10
```

The `10` should end up in your C array too.

Comment: Yes, I think something like this could work in the end. I tried to make a class like this, but the problem with this method is that you loose all of the benefits of having an ndarray. For example, `a.shape` will fail because you really need `a.np_array.shape`. I tried to inherit from `numpy.ndarray`, but my attempts failed. Do you know how one might be able to do that?

Comment: Added some delegation code. Now `a.shape` should give `a.np_array.shape`.

Comment: Of course, redirecting `__getattr__` is exactly what I should have been doing¥. Thanks a lot for the ideas!

Comment: Just a last note or two, it may still be important to overload `__str__` and `__repr__`. Also, since we are essentially using all the attributes of `ndarray`, would it be better to just let numpy raise the exception instead of `Array`?

Comment: Of course, this just a very basic example. You can add more special methods according to your needs like `__str__` and `__repr__` and maybe first of all a very descriptive docstring. You can intercept the exceptions raised by the `np` array and add more information before you re-raise them. If this make things better understandable, do it, if not use the plain NumPy exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your descriptor should return Instance of list-like class which knows about `self._lib` and will update it during normal operation `append`, `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, etc.

Comment: I think you are right, it needs to be a wrapper that returns a wrapped array like Muler's idea, but with the addition of knowledge of whatever lib is being used. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Well `__setitem__` updates both the NumPy array and the C `_lib`. NumPy arrays don't support `append` since there are fixed size.