# How to make the elements of a NumPy array property settable?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, properties

I have a property of a Python object that returns an array.
Now, I can set the setter of that property such that the whole array is settable.
However, I'm missing how to make the elements by themselves settable through the property.

I would expect from a user perspective (given an empty `SomeClass` class):

```
>>> x = SomeClass()
>>> x.array = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x.array[1] = 4
>>> print (x.array)
[1, 4, 3]
```

Now, suppose that `SomeClass.array` is a property defined as

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def array(self):
        return self._a
    @array.setter
    def array(self, a):
        self._a = a
```

Everything still works as above. Also if I force simple NumPy arrays on the setter.

However, if I replace the `return self._a` with a NumPy function (that goes in a vectorised way through the elements) and I replace `self._a = a` with the inverse function, of course the entry does not get set anymore.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = np.array(a)

    @property
    def array(self):
        return np.sqrt(self._a)
    @array.setter
    def array(self, a):
        self._a = np.power(a, 2)
```

Now, the user sees the following output:

```
>>> x = SomeClass([1, 4, 9])
>>> print (x.array)
array([1., 2., 3.])
>>> x.array[1] = 13
>>> print (x.array)    # would expect an array([1., 13., 3.]) now!
array([1., 2., 3.])
```

I think I understand where the problem comes from (the array that NumPy creates during the operation gets its element changed but it doesn't have an effect on the stored array).

What would be a proper implementation of `SomeClass` to make single elements of the array write-accessible individually and thus settable as well?

Thanks a lot for your hints and help,
TheXMA

The points @Jaime made below his answer helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since arrays are mutable objects, the individual items are settable even without a setter function:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self._a = np.asarray(a)
...     @property
...     def arr(self):
...         return self._a
...
>>> a = A([1,2,3])

>>> a.arr
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> a.arr = [4,5,6] # There is no setter...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute

>>> a.arr[1] = 7 # ...but the array is mutable
>>> a.arr
array([1, 7, 3])
```

This is one of the uses of tuples vs. lists, since the latter are mutable, but the former aren't. Anyway, to answer your question: making individual items settable is easy, as long as your getter returns the object itself.

The fancier performance in your second example doesn't seem easy to get in any simple way. I think you could make it happen by making your `SomeClass.array` attribute be a custom class, that either subclasses `ndarray` or wraps an instance of it. Either way would be a lot of nontrivial work.

Comment: OK, that is why I thought the first example would work fine, exactly.

But actually, the second one is what I was aiming for... unfortunately.

Is there nobody who ever did this kind of work, making an array-type data structure a (sort of functional) property of a class and have its elements mutable?

Comment: I'm wondering if you refer to an implementation of the `SomeClass.array` as a Proxy, in a way following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893089/how-to-implement-an-array-like-property-wrapper-in-python) ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea... The problem with the approach in the accepted answer to that question, a class that wraps an ndarray instance, is that only functionality you explicitly wrap will be able, e.g. with the implementation there, you could not do `a.arr += 1`.

Comment: What would be missing there? Does the `__getattr__` forwarding not take care of that?

Comment: You would need to rewrite the `__add__`, `__iadd__`, `__radd__` and the like methods. You could also do some magic with the new `__numpy_ufunc__` method, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.classes.html#arrays-classes). But it is going to end up being messy and a lot of work no matter what you do, I'm afraid.